# Can't purge nvidia drivers, unable to locate package nvidia-docker

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

My ubuntu 16.04 goes into a login loop, so I would like to uninstall all Nivida drivers and reinstall them. But when I run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

I got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-docker
```

I didn't install [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker), probably some programs install it for me.
Is there any other ways to uninstall Nvidia drivers ?